# php destructor behaviour

Tags: php, oop, destructor

im trying to understand php constructor and destructor behaviour. Everything goes as expected with the constructor but i am having trouble getting the destructor to fire implicitly. Ive done all the reading on php.net and related sites, but i cant find an answer to this question.

If i have a simple class, something like:

```
class test{

     public function __construct(){
          print "contructing<br>";
     }

     public function __destruct(){
          print "destroying<br>";
     }
}
```

and i call it with something like:

```
$t = new test;
```

it prints the constructor message. However, i'd expect that when the scripts ends and the page is rendered that the destructor should fire. Of course it doesnt.

If i call `unset($t);` when the scripts ends, of course the destructor fires, but is there a way to get it to fire implicitly?

Answer (score 19):

This is pretty easy to test.

```
<?php

class DestructTestDummy {
    protected $name;

    function __construct($name) {
        echo "Constructing $name\n";
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function __destruct() {
        echo "Destructing $this->name\n";
        //exit;
    }
}

echo "Start script\n";

register_shutdown_function(function() {
    echo "Shutdown function\n";
    //exit
});

$a = new DestructTestDummy("Mr. Unset");
$b = new DestructTestDummy("Terminator 1");
$c = new DestructTestDummy("Terminator 2");

echo "Before unset\n";
unset($a);
echo "After unset\n";


echo "Before func\n";
call_user_func(function() {
    $c = new DestructTestDummy("Mrs. Scopee");
});
echo "After func\n";

$b->__destruct();

exit("Exiting\n");
```

In PHP 5.5.12 this prints:

```
Start script
Constructing Mr. Unset
Constructing Terminator 1
Constructing Terminator 2
Before unset
Destructing Mr. Unset
After unset
Before func
Constructing Mrs. Scopee
Destructing Mrs. Scopee
After func
Destructing Terminator 1
Exiting
Shutdown function
Destructing Terminator 2
Destructing Terminator 1
```

So we can see that the destructor is called when we explicitly unset the object, when it goes out of scope, *and* when the script ends.

Comment: So, it is guaranteed to be called like in `C++` instead of being just Garbage Collected like `Java`, correct?

Comment: @Top-Master Yes, unless perhaps there's a critical error.

Answer (score 4):

The `__destruct()` magic function is executed when the object is deleted/destroyed (using `unset`). It is not called during shutdown of a script. When a PHP script finishes executing, it cleans up the memory, but it doesn't 'delete' objects as such, thus the `__destruct()` methods aren't called.

You may be thinking of the [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), which is fired when your PHP script finishes executing.

```
function shutdown()
{
    // code here
    echo 'this will be called last';
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

Comment: Actually, according to the manual this isn't true. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php. "The destructor method will be called as soon as all references to a particular object are removed or when the object is explicitly destroyed or in any order in shutdown sequence."

Comment: You need to be very careful about trying to write to the browser in a shutdown function - "Shutdown functions are called after closing all opened output buffers" - althuogh stdout is still connected, this may not be the output stream you were using previously

Comment: or get this error message: Object of class LoggerAppenderFile is swept, and therefore its destructor is not called.

Comment: Also when an exception is thrown and not handled the destructor will not be called

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that destructors are automatically called for any remaining objects when the script ends.

Looking though the [manual page on constructors and destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), it seems the only way to bypass destructors entirely is if you call `exit()` from the destructor of an object that is destroyed prior to the object in question.

Are you using `exit()` in any of your destructors? Are there even multiple objects in your script?

If it's not too much trouble, perhaps you could post the actual code in question rather than the sample code you have in your question now. Aside from the typo in your sample constructor, that code *should* call both the constuctor and destructor for your `test` object.

Comment: I think it's more complicated than that. If you put an `exit` in a destructor then the first time the object is destructed it will call any function registered with `register_shutdown_function` and then call any other destructors. If those destructors also contain an `exit` then the script will stop there. i.e., the first call to exit puts the script into shutdown mode, the second forces it to stop immediately. Unless the 2nd exit is inside the shutdown function -- that one behaves more or less like a 'return'.

Answer (score 1):

The __destruct method of a class is called once all references to the object are unset.

For example

```
$dummy = (object) new Class();
```

The destructor is automatically called if the dummy object is set to null or the script is exited.

```
unset($dummy); // or $dummy = null;
//exit(); //also possible
```

However, there are three crucial memory notes to calling the destructor method:

Firstly, the desctructor method should be a public method, not protected or private.

Secondly, refrain from using internal and circular references. For example:

```
class NewDemo
{
     function __construct()
     {
          $this->foo = $this;
     } 
     function __destruct()
     {
          // this method will never be called 
          // and cause memory leaks
          // unset will not clear the internal reference
     }
}
```

The following will not work either:

```
$a = new Class();
$b = new Class();
$a->pointer = $b;
$b->pointer = $a;

unset($a); // will not call destructor
unset($b); // will not call destructor
```

Thirdly, deciding whether destructors are called after output is sent. Using

```
gc_collect_cycles()
```

one can determine whether all destructors are called before sending data to user.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php for the sources and elaborate explanations of magic destruct methods with examples.