# How do you 'release' an XMLWriter from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

[I've updated the question to add the fact that the issue is caused by using an array.]

From the [Notes section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlwriter.openuri.php#refsect1-xmlwriter.openuri-notes) of the `XMLWriter::openUri` PHP doc:

> On Windows, files opened with this function are locked until the writer is released.

If I use a simple variable to assign one `XMLWriter` object, `unlink` does the job and frees the file.
But if an array of `XMLWriter`s is used (I must generate several files concurrently), there is still one/some locked files, that **will only be deleted after the end of the script**.

How can I "release all the writers" and delete the files right then so I can remove the folder?

Using `XMLWriter::openMemory` to 'replace' the file opened with `openURI` works, but feels like a hack...

The three loops are there just to replicate the way my real code works.

```php
$tmp_dir = sys_get_temp_dir().'\dummy2';
mkdir($tmp_dir);
$xml = [];
foreach(['A', 'B'] as $a) {
    $xml[$a] = new XMLWriter();
}
foreach ($xml as $k => $x) {
    $x->openURI($tmp_dir.'\any'.$k.'.xml');
    $x->setIndent(true);
    $x->setIndentString('');
    $x->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $x->startElement('ELEM');
    $x->writeAttribute('ATTRIB', 'SOME_'.$k);
    $x->text('Witty');
    $x->endElement();
    $x->endDocument();
}
foreach ($xml as $k => $x) {
    $x->flush();
    unset($xml[$k]);      //unset alone doesn't clears the file handles
    //$xml->openMemory(); //This works, but seems hacky
}
unset($xml);  // This doesn't clear it either

array_map('unlink', glob($tmp_dir.'\*.*'));
rmdir($tmp_dir);  //Doesn't work, because there is still one, locked, XML file in the folder

// Script ends, file is gone from folder...
```

Comment: The OOP [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/example.xmlwriter-oop.php) uses `outputMemory()` as its last call. Have you tried to see if that releases the locked file?

Comment: With `unset`, you might also have to manually tell the GC to collect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163490/231316. As for hacky, unfortunately the PHP devs just don’t have enough time to test/handle/solve on every platform, so I think this is your best/safest bet

Comment: @KimHallberg The `openMemory()` is only used (as a hack) to 'close' the handle opened by `openURI()`.  
@ChrisHaas Garbage collection doesn't seem to have an effect.
I'll keep the hacky way for now and hope it doesn't affect memory too much in the long run.

Comment: @Goozak I didn't say `openMemory()` I said the example used `outputMemory()` and asked if you'd tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that `unset( $x )` in the final loop (**instead** of `unset( $xml[$k] )`), followed by `unset( $xml )` is the solution.  No more file lock and no need to call the superfluous `openMemory()`!